# Quais são as boas práticas para se trabalhar com Banco de Dados Legado em Django?

Tags: django, python-2.7

Tenho um banco de dados legado e gostaria de saber quais boas práticas para nome de tabelas, ou dicas de como usar inflections(como no Rails) para Django na última versão.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao site, user1320! Seria possível editar sua pergunta para torná-la mais clara e específica? Por exemplo, você quer saber se o Django possui algum padrão de nomenclatura de tabelas, ou "boas práticas" em geral (o que seria um pouco amplo)? Sugiro mostrar exemplos de nomenclatura da sua base legada, e o tipo de resultado que quer atingir. Obrigado!

Answer (score 9):

A "melhor prática" seria deixar que o próprio Django atribuísse os nomes das tabelas e dos campos, mas isso não se aplica ao seu caso, certo? Se tem um banco de dados legado, pode manter sua estrutura tal como está - não há necessidade de fazer modificações (exceto em um caso, como explicarei a seguir).

### Criando modelos automaticamente

O Django possui uma ferramenta chamada [`inspectdb`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-inspectdb) para facilitar a criação dos seus modelos, quando você já possui um banco de dados pronto. Você pode usá-la para "dar a partida", mas em geral adaptações serão necessárias.

### Modelos gerenciados ou não

O django possui uma ferramenta chamda [`syncdb`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/django-admin/#syncdb) (nas versões futuras, será feito obsoleto e substituído por [`migrate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#migrate-app-label-migrationname)) que cuida da criação das tabelas, seus campos e índices automaticamente, a partir dos modelos definidos. Nas versões futuras, também contará com ferramentas de migração de esquema. Quando você usa um modelo assim, ele é chamado **gerenciado** (*managed*).

Caso você não queira fazer uso dessa funcionalidade - criando e mantendo suas tabelas de outra forma - você pode marcá-lo como **não gerenciado** (*unmanaged*). Isso é feito através de um atributo na classe `Meta` do seu modelo:

```python
class Pessoa(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    primeiro_nome = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'nome_da_tabela'
```

Note que o fato da tabela já existir não significa automaticamente que você precise de um modelo não gerenciado - você pode pegar a tabela do jeito que está, e deixar que o Django te auxilie nas futuras migrações de esquema. Isso é uma opção sua.

### Nomes de tabelas e de colunas

Se você não especificar nada, o Django procurará/criará tabelas e colunas com um nome padronizado, inferido a partir do nome de sua *app* e os nomes dos seus modelos e campos. Se você precisar especificá-los manualmente, basta usar `db_table` (como já demonstrado no exemplo acima) para o nome da tabela e/ou [`db_column`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/fields/#db-column) para os nomes das colunas:

```python
class Pessoa(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, db_column="pessoa_id")
    primeiro_nome = models.CharField(max_length=70, db_column="nome")
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'nome_da_tabela'
```

Também há outras opções para se customizar a integração com o DB (como `db_index` e `db_tablespace`), consulte a documentação do Django para mais detalhes.

### Toda tabela precisa de uma chave primária

Esse é o único caso em que talvez uma adaptação nas suas tabelas seja necessária. Para o ORM do Django funcionar, é necessário que toda tabela tenha uma chave primária, e essa chave primária tem de ser **simples** (i.e. uma única coluna - não pode ser uma chave composta). Se você não especificar nada, o Django assumirá que você possui um campo númérico chamado `id`. Se você precisar especificar, basta usar a propriedade `primary_key`, como já demonstrado nos exemplos anteriores.

### Sempre que possível, use o nome das tabelas no singular

Levou um tempinho pra eu descobrir o que eram "inflections", mas pelo que eu entendi é aquela funcionalidade onde o Rails automaticamente "pluraliza" o nome da tabela pra você, certo? Não há nada parecido com isso no Django, o comportamento padrão é usar o nome no singular mesmo para as tabelas (e na minha opinião esse é o ideal - pluralizar introduz uma complicação desnecessária para resolver um problema que não existe).

Se você **realmente precisa** que os nomes estejam no plural, use `db_table` manualmente como explicado acima.

Answer (score 0):

As database views também podem ser utilizadas nos seus models, para isso inclua no inspectdb o parametro --include-views, entretanto, providencie a inclusão de uma chave primária em suas views, como @mgibsonbr já citou, são necessárias.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ... AS
   id ROW_NUMBER() OVER(),
   field1 ...
   fieldn ...
```