# Como importar banco de dados para os models do Django?

Tags: mysql, django, engenharia-reversa

Tenho uma aplicação que está praticamente pronta. Foi desenvolvida em PHP, através do Framework Laravel.

Eu já tenho o banco de dados e todos alguns dados já inseridos para realizar testes.

Porém, como estou fazendo alguns testes com o framework Django, eu gostaria de usar esse banco da aplicação anterior e usá-la no Django.

Ou seja, queria saber se tem alguma engenharia reversa, onde eu posso criar os `models` do Django a partir de um banco de dados  já existente.

Detalhes: O meu banco de dados é `Mysql`.

Comment: Relacionado: ["Quais são as boas práticas para se trabalhar com Banco de Dados Legado em Django?"](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2287/215)

Comment: Fui castigado com um -1 opressor, kkkkk

Comment: Eu, hein? Não vi o motivo, afinal pessoalmente não considero a pergunta duplicata (ou teria votado como tal), e de todo modo em termos práticos eu gostei da resposta.

Comment: @mgibsonbr pior é que na maioria das vezes o pessoal da -1 para perguntas duplicadas, mas a ideia do site não é essa. Perguntas duplicadas devem ser fechadas, e não negativadas. Pois a final, pode ser uma maneira diferente de se chegar a uma resposta já existente no site (tipo um atalho)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim, o framework Django possui uma ferramenta pronta para isso.

Trata-se do comando `inspectdb`.

Esse comando fará com que o `Django` analise o seu banco de dados e gere uma saída contendo definições dos models. Ou seja, a abstração do seu banco será gerada automaticamente pelo Django para as tabelas inspecionadas.

Você pode capturar essa saída para um arquivo `Python` utilizando o operador `>`.

Então, depois de configurar o `Mysql` no seu `settings.py` do Django, basta fazer isso:

```
 ./manager.py inspectdb > app/models.py
```