# Como fazer Engenharia Reversa de banco MYSQL com SqlAlchemy?

Tags: python, flask, engenharia-reversa

Fiz essa pergunta qui no Stackoverflow esses dias atrás:

[Como importar banco de dados para os models do Django?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/126266/como-importar-banco-de-dados-para-os-models-do-django)

Porém agora, preciso de algo parecido para `Flask`.

Tenho um banco pronto, usando o `MYSQL`.

Quero fazer uma engenharia reversa do meu banco de dados, transformando todos os dados em `Models` do `SqlAlchemy`.

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

Ter as tabelas em memória como objetos Pythonicos é algo que o SqlAlchemy faz sozinho.

No entanto,a aprtir daí, gerar um arquivo '.py' com os modelos em si,
é algo que precisa ser feito manualmente - 
você cria o texto do arquivo como uma string, e grava isso num arquivo - 
pode-se usar um dos engines de template, como os que já são usados
em frameworks, ou o próprio 'format' do Python -

Então, para introspecar um banco e ter os objetos table 
'vivos':

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine import reflection
engine = create_engine('<sua url>')
insp = reflection.Inspector.from_engine(engine)
print (insp.get_table_names())
```

(código de: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/reflection.html)

Um esqueleto de como gerar o código Python a partir de introspecção seria

```
from sqlalchemy import Table, MetaData, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine import reflection

engine = create_engine('<sua url>')


def create_schema_source():

    result = """\from app import db\n\n"""
    meta = MetaData()
    for table_name in engine.table_names():
        table_text = """class {}(db.Model):\n""".format(table_name.title().replace("_",""))
        table = Table(table_name, m, autoload_with=engine)
        for column in table.columns:
            col_text = """    {name} = db.Column(db.{type}(), {{extras}})\n""".format(
                name=column.name, 
                type=repr(column.type).strip('()'),
                )
            extras = ""
            # neste ponto inspecionar os atributos de column em que estiver interessado
            # e montar a string extras com alguns 'if' - 
            # ex.: ( column.foreign_keys, column.primary_key)
            table_text += col_text.format(extras=extras)
        result +=  table_text + "\n\n"
    return result

print(create_schema_source())
```

O esqueleto acima funciona, como não preciso no momento, só não me alonguei em detalhar o que entra na string de 'extras" que são todos os demais parâmetros que são usados para construir uma coluna - os dados estão disponíveis no objeto do tipo "column'  - eu sugiro que você use o terminal interativo do Python, obtenha um objeto 'column' desses, veja os atributos disponíveis com `dir` e os use para completar a função acima.